# Can't load bootstrap glyphicon fonts on mvc net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gruntjs, glyphicons

I'm having a problem with the glyphicons-font when I publish the website under a virtual path. I'm getting a 404 response code for all the bootstrap's fonts. The fonts are being looked under this folder:

```
/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/
```

But they're actually under this folder when the site is deployed:

```
XXX/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/
```

I'm registering my BundleConfig.cs like this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/bowercss")
    // bower:css
    .Include("~/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
    .Include("~/bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
    .Include("~/bower_components/bootstrap-switch/dist/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
    .Include("~/bower_components/angular-ui-switch/angular-ui-switch.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
    .Include("~/bower_components/angular-xeditable/dist/css/xeditable.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
    // endbower
);
```

And on my Web.config I have added support to the fonts:

```
<staticContent>
          <!-- Add support to .woof2 files -->
          <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
          <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
          <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
          <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
          <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
</staticContent>
```

Update 12/12/2016:

I've tried all the solutions that Aravind proposed, yet without any luck.
I even copied all the fonts to the root folder and overrode the font-family in a custom css to point to the new files and it doesn't work either:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

How can I get the fonts correctly download when the site is deployed under the virtual path?

[image: font response]

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your _Layout file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Or

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Update 1:

Use these can and download the files and add to your folder.

Alternatively you can use nuget packages

Go to package manager console and use this command

```
Install-Package glyphicon
```

You can even add it to ur project by right clicking on the solution search for nuget packages and click install.

Comment: Hi thanks but I want to include the fonts from my folder not from the cdn.

Comment: Download and add it to ur folder by selecting all and pasting it in a css file and name that way.

Comment: I cannot install that package we're using bower to install the frontend dependencies.

Comment: because nuget package manager doesn't have all the dependencies that we need.

Answer (score 0):

1. In file “_Layout.cshtml” you should have such this code for **bundles** folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> </title>

    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/master/css"); 
</head>
<body>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/master/js");
    @RenderBody() 
</body>
</html>
```

2. Then you should have a folder in the root directory of your project with the name “bundles”. If you don't have it, create it.
3. Then copy the font’s folder which contains glyphicons’ files. To clarify see [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pthfB.png)
4. Now, add a font name in the class of an element like this code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg ">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>search 
</button>
```